Angular working fine on localy but not on github action
I'm currently working on an Angular project that builds successfully on my local machine using the command ng build --prod. However, when I try to run the same build process in GitHub Actions, it fails with errors.
Here’s the relevant part of my GitHub Actions workflow YAML file:
name: Node.js CI

on:
  push:
    branches: [ "master" ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ "master" ]

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    strategy:
      matrix:
        node-version: [18.19.x]

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v4
        with:
          fetch-depth: 0  # Fetch all history for accurate versioning

      - name: Use Node.js ${{ matrix.node-version }}
        uses: actions/setup-node@v4
        with:
          node-version: ${{ matrix.node-version }}
          cache: 'npm'
          cache-dependency-path: package.json

      - uses: actions/cache@v4
        with:
          path: ~/.npm
          key: ${{ runner.os }}-node-${{ hashFiles('**/package-lock.json') }}
          restore-keys: |
            ${{ runner.os }}-node-

      - run: npm install -g @angular/cli
        name: Install Angular CLI

      - run: npm install --legacy-peer-deps
        name: Install dependencies

      - run: ng build --prod
        name: Compile for production

Issue Details:

Node.js Version: I'm using Node.js version 18.19.x in my GitHub
Actions workflow but i'm using version 15.14.x locally.
Local Build Success: The command ng build --prod
works perfectly on my local environment.
Error Message: The build fails in GitHub Actions, but I haven’t been able to capture the exact error message. It seems related to dependency resolution.

Questions:

Why does the build work locally but fail in GitHub Actions?
Are there specific configurations or environment variables I need to set in the CI environment?
Is there a recommended way to debug this issue?
Should I add additional logging or modify my workflow steps?
Are there any known compatibility issues with Angular CLI and Node.js versions that I should be aware of?

Additional Context:
I've ensured that all dependencies are correctly defined in package.json and package-lock.json.
I am using npm install --legacy-peer-deps to handle potential peer dependency issues.
there is the log of actions , noted that this errors is not mentionned when i run ng build --prod locally :
Run ng build
- Generating browser application bundles (phase: setup)...
    TypeScript compiler options "target" and "useDefineForClassFields" are set to "ES2022" and "false" respectively by the Angular CLI. To control ECMA version and features use the Browerslist configuration. For more information, see https://angular.io/guide/build#configuring-browser-compatibility
    NOTE: You can set the "target" to "ES2022" in the project's tsconfig to remove this warning.
✔ Browser application bundle generation complete.
✔ Browser application bundle generation complete.

./node_modules/admin-lte/dist/css/adminlte.min.css - Warning: Module Warning (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Warning

(11:62244) autoprefixer: Replace color-adjust to print-color-adjust. The color-adjust shorthand is currently deprecated.

./src/app/modules/exemplaire-document/new-exemplaire/new-exemplaire.component.scss?ngResource - Warning: Module Warning (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Warning

(62:3) autoprefixer: start value has mixed support, consider using flex-start instead

./src/app/modules/missions/executer-mission/executer-mission.component.scss?ngResource - Warning: Module Warning (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Warning

(47:3) autoprefixer: start value has mixed support, consider using flex-start instead

./src/app/modules/missions/executer-mission/executer-mission.component.scss?ngResource - Warning: Module Warning (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Warning

(48:3) autoprefixer: start value has mixed support, consider using flex-start instead

./src/app/modules/precomvt/new-precomvt/new-precomvt.component.scss?ngResource - Warning: Module Warning (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Warning

(5:3) autoprefixer: start value has mixed support, consider using flex-start instead

./src/app/modules/precomvt/new-precomvt/new-precomvt.component.scss?ngResource - Warning: Module Warning (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Warning

(205:3) autoprefixer: start value has mixed support, consider using flex-start instead

./src/app/modules/tickets/panneau-ticket/panneau-ticket.component.scss?ngResource - Warning: Module Warning (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Warning

(9:3) autoprefixer: end value has mixed support, consider using flex-end instead

./src/app/modules/tickets/panneau-ticket/panneau-ticket.component.scss?ngResource - Warning: Module Warning (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Warning

(45:3) autoprefixer: start value has mixed support, consider using flex-start instead



Error: Error: node_modules/ngx-print/lib/ngx-print.directive.d.ts:72:90 - error TS2344: Type '{ previewOnly: { alias: "previewOnly"; required: false; }; printSectionId: { alias: "printSectionId"; required: false; }; printTitle: { alias: "printTitle"; required: false; }; useExistingCss: { alias: "useExistingCss"; required: false; }; ... 5 more ...; styleSheetFile: { ...; }; }' does not satisfy the constraint '{ [key: string]: string; }'.
  Property '"previewOnly"' is incompatible with index signature.
    Type '{ alias: "previewOnly"; required: false; }' is not assignable to type 'string'.

72     static ɵdir: i0.ɵɵDirectiveDeclaration<NgxPrintDirective, "button[ngxPrint]", never, { "previewOnly": { "alias": "previewOnly"; "required": false; }; "printSectionId": { "alias": "printSectionId"; "required": false; }; "printTitle": { "alias": "printTitle"; "required": false; }; "useExistingCss": { "alias": "useExistingCss"; "required": false; }; "printDelay": { "alias": "printDelay"; "required": false; }; "closeWindow": { "alias": "closeWindow"; "required": false; }; "bodyClass": { "alias": "bodyClass"; "required": false; }; "openNewTab": { "alias": "openNewTab"; "required": false; }; "printStyle": { "alias": "printStyle"; "required": false; }; "styleSheetFile": { "alias": "styleSheetFile"; "required": false; }; }, {}, never, never, true, never>;
                                                                                            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~



Error: Process completed with exit code 1.

Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

First try to build it locally with node version 18.19.x  (maybe use a docker container or nvm (https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm), or change the github action version. Also run npm ci instead of npm installl. It should behave the same locally. If you switch local versions using nvm, it should also start with an empty npm cache, which will probably give you some probable causes

@EsaïeNjongssi search the logs of error and please update that on the question

@NarenMurali , i have update the post by lmentionning logs of errors. is it enough to troubleshoot it ?

Firstly make sure you use the compatible version of node with angular.
You can use the below link to get the proper version of node needed.
Angular.dev - Version compatibility
After doing this, you should also checkout this ngx-print  - github issue.
Which highlights that the version of ngx-print should be compatible with your version of angular.

